# How do I specify header files for make headers_install in an out-of-tree kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I couldn't find any information regarding this in kbuild [modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) documentation and only an oblique reference (suggesting that it's possible) in the [headers_install](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/headers_install.txt) documentation.

> The "make headers_install" command can be run in the top level directory of the
>   kernel source code (or using a standard out-of-tree build).

I have an out-of-tree kernel module with an associated header file (I have #defines for an IOCTL), and I want to provide that header file as part of the module installation. It seems like the in-tree way for kernel modules to provide header files (for userspace use) is to place them in include/linux/. What do I have to do for this to work for out-of-tree?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be another case where I didn't read all the manuals... the manual needed is the [makefiles](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) documentation for kbuild...

> The kernel includes a set of headers that is exported to userspace.
>   Many headers can be exported as-is but other headers require a
>   minimal pre-processing before they are ready for user-space.
>   The pre-processing does:
>
> - drop kernel-specific annotations
> - drop include of compiler.h
> - drop all sections that are kernel internal (guarded by ifdef **KERNEL**)
>
> Each relevant directory contains a file name "Kbuild" which specifies the
>   headers to be exported.
>   See subsequent chapter for the syntax of the Kbuild file.
>
> --- 7.1 header-y
>
> header-y specifies header files to be exported.
>
> ```
>   Example:
>         #include/linux/Kbuild
>         header-y += usb/
>         header-y += aio_abi.h
> ```

Comment: It's already done when kernel internal headers were split to UAPI and internal usage.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be deprecated. The `headers_install` target does not exist for out-of-tree module builds (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68659587/19041593)).