# Linux kernel out-of-tree module, installation of uapi headers issue

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I have an external out-of-tree linux kernel module, say **foo**. Therein, I have a directory **include/uapi/** that should, I assume, contain **Kbuild** file defining inclusion rules and/or headers to export. The directory **include/uapi/** on its turn contains one more directory **linux** having the target user-API headers in, say three files **foo.h bar.h baz.h**

Ok, I have defined this **Kbuild** file inside **include/uapi** and it contains:

> header-y += linux/

Then, inside **include/uapi/linux** directory I've defined one more **KBuild** and it has the content:

> header-y += foo.h bar.h baz.h

Now I am expecting that upon running the command

> make -C /lib/modules/5.4.48-dannftk/build M=/home/dannftk/foo INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/home/dannftk/my_exported_headers/ headers_install

I will get the headers installed in the **/home/dannftk/my_exported_headers/** directory, instead, I am getting the error saying:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'headers_install'.  Stop.

- /home/dannftk/foo - the path the out-of-tree module discussed is located by
- /lib/modules/5.4.48-dannftk/build - the build directory of the kernel, it points to **/usr/src/linux-5.4.48** containing the source code of the kernel, actually, I am on Gentoo Linux

May someone give me a hint what I am doing wrongly? Am I incorrectly setting rules for Kbuild? Or maybe I am locating them in unexpected for the kernel build system directories?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

I personally consider this issue as a bad Kbuild error message. It's too confusing.

The answer is in [linux documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt):

```
--- 2.3 Targets

When building an external module, only a subset of the "make"
targets are available.

make -C $KDIR M=$PWD [target]

The default will build the module(s) located in the current
directory, so a target does not need to be specified. All
output files will also be generated in this directory. No
attempts are made to update the kernel source, and it is a
precondition that a successful "make" has been executed for the
kernel.

modules
    The default target for external modules. It has the
    same functionality as if no target was specified. See
    description above.

modules_install
    Install the external module(s). The default location is
    /lib/modules/<kernel_release>/extra/, but a prefix may
    be added with INSTALL_MOD_PATH (discussed in section 5).

clean
    Remove all generated files in the module directory only.

help
    List the available targets for external modules.
```

There were some hacks available in older kernel versions, as adding `header-y += ...` into Kbuild file, but, as you see, it's not the official approach.

Looks like developers of out-of-tree modules should take care of headers installation manually, without reusing of linux kernel make rules.