# Yocto external kernel module including public header

Tags: header-files, yocto, kernel-module

I have written an external kernel module, very close to the hello_mod example:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-skeleton/recipes-kernel/hello-mod/hello-mod_0.1.bb

However, my kernel module also provides a public header file to be provided to all code using the module. However, this header is not installed to sysroot, nor to populate_sdk.

How can I achieve this? Do I have to manually add the file via FILES_${PN}_dev or modify the Makefile?

Comment: You're going to have to get the header into the sysroot somehow.  The best option is probably to modify the makefile's install target and let yocto automatically populate packages.

Comment: @StephenNewell thanks! Do you by any chance have an example for such Makefile extensions that are still compatible with kernel module build?

Answer (score 1):

After chatting on yocto mailinglist I got the impression, that it is uncommon for kernel modules to install their own headers. Hence I opted for a simple do_install_append() into [hello-mod.bb](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-kernel/hello-mod/hello-mod_0.1.bb?h=bernard), like this:

```
do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${includedir}/
    install -m 644 ${S}/header.h ${D}${includedir}/header.h
}
FILES_${PN} += "${includedir}"
```

With a DEPENDS entry other recipes can now access the header via sysroot.

Regarding a solution inside the module Makefile: I found some reference about "make headers_install" but couldn't figure out to integrate this into my module Makefile, see [How do I specify header files for make headers_install in an out-of-tree kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866880/how-do-i-specify-header-files-for-make-headers-install-in-an-out-of-tree-kernel)